Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated. The ts client does not correspond to the pda of the Solana program
Issue
I encountered a strange issue where the PDA found using findProgramAddressSync in the TypeScript client does not match the PDA found in the Solana program instruction account structure, despite using the same seeds.
 Error: AnchorError caused by account: inviter_config. Error Code: ConstraintSeeds. Error Number: 2006. Error Message: A seeds constraint was violated.
Program log: Left:
Program log: Gi7Pn7CSQrRL5LV5Jb9yuEzE5N86RsSn5drFYXAz4Rku
Program log: Right:
Program log: 3LwQF3aAXbvGEVXfEQbajDL8vkMH9xx3qxHVGAMTmK9j
      at Function.parse (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:167:14)
      at translateError (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/error.ts:276:35)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:35:29)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

Code
ts client
async mintCat (player: Keypair, mint_quantity = 1, inviter_pubkey = PublicKey.default) {
        const [playerConfigPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [Buffer.from("player_config"), player.publicKey.toBuffer()],
            this.program.programId
        );
        const [inviterConfigPDA] = anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [Buffer.from("player_config"), inviter_pubkey.toBuffer()],
            this.program.programId
        );
        console.log("inviterConfigPDA: ", inviterConfigPDA.toString());
        const tx = await this.program.methods
            .mintScratchcard(inviter_pubkey, mint_quantity)
            .accounts({
                playerConfig: playerConfigPDA,
                inviterConfig: inviterConfigPDA,
            })
            .rpc();
    }
}

Solana program
#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(inviter_pubkey: Pubkey)]
pub struct MintCat<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    player: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = player,
        seeds = [b"player_config".as_ref(), player.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<PlayerConfig>()
    )]
    player_config: Account<'info, PlayerConfig>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = player,
        seeds = [b"player_config".as_ref(), inviter_pubkey.as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<PlayerConfig>()
    )]
    inviter_config: Account<'info, PlayerConfig>,
}
impl<'info> MintCat<'info> {
    pub fn process(ctx: Context<MintCat>, inviter_pubkey: Pubkey, mint_quantity: u8) -> Result<()> {...}
}

Attempts made so far
1. Replace inviter_pubkey directly with Pubkey::default(), and the program works without any problems.
 #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = player,
        seeds = [b"player_config".as_ref(), inviter_pubkey.to_bytes().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<PlayerConfig>()
    )]
    inviter_config: Account<'info, PlayerConfig>,

replace:
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = player,
        seeds = [b"player_config".as_ref(), Pubkey::default().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = 8 + std::mem::size_of::<PlayerConfig>()
    )]
    inviter_config: Account<'info, PlayerConfig>,

2. print the inviter_pubkey && Pubkey::default()

The default value for inviter is PublicKey.default

From the printed result, the two Publickeys are the same：
pub fn process(ctx: Context<MintCat>, inviter_pubkey: Pubkey, mint_quantity: u8) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("inviter_pubkey: {:?}", inviter_pubkey);
        msg!("pubkey default: {:?}", Pubkey::default());
        msg!("inviter_config: {:?}", ctx.accounts.inviter_config.key());
      ....
}

> Program logged: "inviter_pubkey: 11111111111111111111111111111111"
> Program logged: "pubkey default: 11111111111111111111111111111111"
> Program logged: "inviter_config: Gi7Pn7CSQrRL5LV5Jb9yuEzE5N86RsSn5drFYXAz4Rku"


Everything looks good and works as expected on my machine.
Some things to debug,

Could you check that you are using the correct programId, maybe you updated it and forgot to update the IDL

Try adding system_program for creating the PDAs init_if_needed



Thank you. It was my own mistake that caused this problem
